# asp.net web form in multiple browser tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a grid view and an edit button in the grid view. On edit button click I am opening a new aspx page that has text fields for input the data. When a user copies the URL of the gridview and opens it in a new tab of any browser then click on the edit button for two different records. If the user changes anything in the first tab and submits it. It changes the info for the record on the second tab. It is happening because I am passing userid in session to the form aspx page and session got updated when user opens the second record in the new tab.

Are there only two ways to passing data to aspx page?

1. using session
2. using a query string

I don't want to use the query string.
Please help thank you.

Comment: What problem you are trying to solve here? Data populated in the controls in the page also sent to the server.

Comment: the problem is the when user try to change something in the first tab and submit it changes the record in the second tab

Comment: Are you seriously worried about a user Update Race Conditioning himself? That is not something to worry about. Multiple user, that is where this worry should start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example

Comment: But there is a HTML way to make sure the existing "frame" is re-used, rather then opening additional ones. That target property on Links? That is to avoid having multiple instance of the same page open. Just use something like Primary Key of the record as targetname. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp This will make accidents unlikely.

Comment: I am afraid yes I am worried about the Race Condition because of the records might contain some lengthy and similar data so the user might want to copy-paste some from one record to another and for that purpose, they will be opening multiple tabs of the same form and might end up replacing data

Comment: I don't think that target property will work because they can simply open a record by copy the URL of the grid to another tab and then click on the edit button

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a ASP.Net application, so at the end of the day there is only that much you can do. You can request some things off the browser, but if he actually does it is entirely up to it.

You can make it unlikely to happen by accident, using the [HTML Links target property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp). This requests the browser to re-use any alread open tabs for this record. But that will not prevent a dedicated person from still opening 2 copies.

A pretty simple way to avoid race conditions in general, is the [SQL rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) column. You retreive the rowversion with the rest. You keep it along in a hidden formular field (that is what they are there for). When writing the update, check if it still matches before the write. If yes, you update. If not, **somebody** has modified the record since then and you reject the update. Can be the same user in another tab, can be another user at the end of the world. Could be that this tab was opened a year ago, surviving on sleep mode. It does not mater - any change trips this protection.